# Providing a Base Class Constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it necessary to always provide your base class with a constructor? For example if I had the following base class, and then some derived classes.

```
class Animal
{
 public:

    //Is this constructor necessary?
    Animal(); 

    virtual ~Animal();
};

class Zebra: public Animal
{
 public:
    Zebra();
   ~Zebra();
};

class Elephant: public Animal
{
 public:
    Elephant();
   ~Elephant();
};
```

Assuming that I am creating Animal pointers and then dynamically allocating new Zebra and Elephant objects. If I never intend to create an Animal object, then is there any actual need to explicitly create an Animal constructor?

Comment: `If I never intend to create an Animal object` Strictly speaking, you _do_ create Animal objects whenever you create Zebra or Elephant objects.

Comment: In this specific case, a user specified constructor is not required, and the compiler will generate the default constructor for you. There are certain situtiations, depending on the C++ language level, and the class's particulars, where a constructor will be required. If one is omitted no compilation error will result, but there will be no way to construct the class.

Comment: @tkausl So the base class constructor will be called when creating Zebra or Elephant objects because they are technically Animal objects?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for the answer Sam. Although not necessary for compilation, is it considered best practice to explicitly define a base class constructor?

Comment: The nice thing about "best practices" is that everyone has a different one.

Comment: You don't need to redeclare the destructor in the derived classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly provide constructor.
A default one is generated (if you don't provide other constructor).

so

```
class Animal
{
public:

    virtual ~Animal();
};
```

is sufficient.

Derived classes constructors would call Base class constructor (explicitly of implicitly).